# Is Hatha Yoga Pradipika an authentic hindu text?

Tags: yoga

Is [Hatha Yoga Pradipika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_Yoga_Pradipika) an authentic Hinduism text as Pathanjali Yoga Sutras, Vivekananda Raja Yoga etc.,?

Comment: Related [meta question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/609/can-we-cite-hatha-yoga-pradipika-for-nath-sampraday-related-questions)

Comment: Yeah, it is a duplicate of the question @TriyugiNarayanMani

Comment: But it cannot be marked here :)

Comment: Just curious... what is your criteria to say a text is authentic or not?

Comment: @Ambi if it is written by an authentic person or accepted by an authentic person or accepted by Hindu community etc.,